# How to obtain Laplace transformation of the following exponential function?

Tags: laplace-transform

Is there a general expression for Laplace transform of an exponential function of the following form?

$$\mathcal{L}\left(e^{-x\left(t\right)}\right)$$

where $x(t)$ is an arbitrary function which has positive value at any $t$. Can Laplace transformation be expressed in terms of $X(s)$ where

$$X(s) =\mathcal{L}\left(x(t)\right)$$

Comment: Is there a general form for the Laplace Transform of $x^2(t)$ for an arbitrary $x(t)$ in terms of $X(s)$?  While the convolution theorem can be used, how would you propose to find the LT of $x^n(t)$ other than a nested set of convolution integrals?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you have refereed to. You want to say that if the exponential function is expanded using Taylor series, it will result in x^n (t) @MarkViola and such a function can not be transformed using Laplace transformation.

Comment: Well,if the LT of $x^n$ is a $n-1$-fold convolution of $x(t)$, then why would you expect a simple(r) form for $e^{-x(t)}$?

Comment: Sir, how can the convolution theorem be used to transform a simple function (i.e. x^2(t))? @MarkViola